# looking for "my-account/edit-address/billing" in woocommerce php files?

Tags: php, wordpress, validation, woocommerce

**hi,**

I'm working on a WordPress project.

woocommerce in the page bellow has a billing address form that i want to edit and add server-side form validation.

but i cant find the form page location in woocommerce's php files.

> **/my-account/edit-address/billing/**

Where is the form page location?

Is there any function that i can use for edit this page?

And how can i do that?

**Thanks alot**

Answer (score 3):

You find the file in:

> {wordpress-path}/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/myaccount/form-edit-address.php